# How do you do partial staging with svn?

Tags: git, svn, patch

I tried to apply my "merge not all the changes" skill from `git` to `svn`. There's no such thing as interactive staging in `svn`, no doubt about it. But you can make a patch, and apply several hunks from it, and do a commit. And so on. Or so I thought.

With `git`, not only had I no issue with committing selected hunks, but also I was able to edit hunks (select which parts of hunks to commit). With `svn`, I was able to do first commit. After that, things got messy. Consider this diff:

```
diff --git a/lib/simplegit.rb b/lib/simplegit.rb
index dd5ecc4..57399e0 100644
--- a/lib/simplegit.rb
+++ b/lib/simplegit.rb
@@ -22,7 +22,7 @@ class SimpleGit
   end

   def log(treeish = 'master')
-    command("git log -n 25 #{treeish}")
+    command("git log -n 30 #{treeish}")
   end

   def blame(path)
```

For patch to apply, I should fix `-22,7 +22,7` part for it to reflect current position of a hunk. With `git` I never needed such things. Does `git` uses looser settings when applying a patch? Is there a way to ease this workflow with svn? Is there anything I can specify when applying a patch to make it not so strict?

**UPD** It's not so much about `svn`. For example, I add to a file three lines:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

With `git` I can run `git add -p`, press <kbd>e</kbd> (edit hunk) and remove `line 2`. Then `git` successfully stages this:

```
line 1
line 3
```

With `svn`, when I do: `svn diff > 1.patch`, remove second line from a patch file, and try to apply it back (`patch -p0 < 1.patch`), it doesn't work out:

```
patch: **** malformed patch at line ..:
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this line does the magic:

```
index dd5ecc4..57399e0 100644
```

This allows Git to track the commits. So it knows which hunks have been applied and which haven't been. Subversion, on the other hand, has no way to track parts of patches. It uses "all or nothing" approach when it comes to commits.

If you still want to partially commit in Subversion without going insane, here is what you can do:

- Create a Git repository of the code in subversion
- Edit the commits until they are as you want them
- Export each commit as a single patch
- Apply each patch in order to Subversion

Or you can try one of the many Git-Subversion bridges. But you need to understand that Subversion is a tool from the "Dark Ages". It's not "Stone Age" like CVS but it still lacks a lot of the fancy features which DCVS brings out of the box.

Comment: It's no so much about `svn`, but about `diff + patch`. And I believe your guess is wrong, the question is particularly about applying hunks that was edited. `But you need to understand that Subversion is a tool from the "Dark Ages".` Pretty arguable statement. I thought so too, but after a half a year using it, I changed my mind. It surely worse, but not that much people tend to think. That is, I don't mind using it.

Comment: @x-yuri: The Dark Ages comment is tongue-in-cheek; SVN is a big step from CVS but it's another big step to DVCS. Git has many features to work with hunks while SVN is oblivious to the concept. The same goes for the command line tool `patch`. Which is why I suggest to do everything in Git and then export it to SVN. changelists http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.changelists.html